# How to enable multi-site function in wordpress 3.0?

Tags: wordpress

There are lots of new properties in wordpress 3.0, one of the most important is the multi-site function, which was implemented in wordpress MU. So, How can i enable multi-site function in wordpress 3.0? Does it support standalone subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for [Create a Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).

Also note that you need to enable the variable `WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE` in wp_config.php

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

Just before

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

Answer (score 0):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Network_SubPanel

yes, by default, it works just like it used to for single sites.